# Physical quantities to decimal power

Tags: units, arbitrary-precision

How can I get Mathematica to properly simplify physical quantities with dimensions to decimal power, such as $1 \frac{1}{\text{s}^{0.7}}\text{dynes}\text{/(}\text{cm}^2\text{Pa})$ that should simplify to just $\frac{1}{10} \frac{1}{\text{s}^{0.7}}$ ?

```
Quantity[1, "Dynes"/("Centimeters"^2*"Pascals"*"Seconds"^(7/10))] // UnitConvert

(* Quantity[1/10, 1/("Seconds")^(7/10)] *)
```

but not

```
Quantity[1, "Dynes"/("Centimeters"^2*"Pascals"*"Seconds"^(0.7))] // UnitConvert

(* Quantity[1, ("Dynes")/(("Centimeters")^2 "Pascals" ("Seconds")^0.7)] *)
```

I also noticed that taking to the 0.5 power works:

```
Quantity[1, "Dynes"/("Centimeters"^2*"Pascals"*"Seconds"^(0.5))] // UnitConvert

(* Quantity[0.1, 1/("Seconds")^0.5] *)
```

The workaround with replacing the decimal number with a fraction works, but there should be a better way. I also looked for a way to specify that the number $0.7$ should be considered an exact number, but no luck.

Comment: Look up `Rationalize[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Guess ... points out

```
Quantity[1, "Dynes"/("Centimeters"^2*"Pascals"*"Seconds"^(0.7))] // 
   Rationalize // UnitConvert
```

> ```
> Quantity[1/10, 1/"Seconds"^(7/10)]
> ```

does the job.